# Octez 17.3 compilation error

Tags: node, rpc, protocol, error, octez

[image]This compilation error appears everytime I run "opam install octez". I have no problem installing previous versions but there seems to be issues with installing octez-node 17.3.

Comment: Please state OS stats.

Comment: Mac OS Sonoma version 14.0